# Android - keep service responsive from lockscreen

Tags: java, android, event-handling, lockscreen, android-7.0-nougat

So I have a counter app that uses a `VolumeProviderCompat` to make a service listen to volume up / down keys. Vol Up = increment, vol down = decrement. This should also be doable from lockscreen - which it is, but only if the device hasn't been locked for too long.

If the device has been locked for a moment (~minutes), the app will not react to key inputs unless the power button is pressed beforehand.

How do I keep the service responsive?
(Always-on display is enabled, power saver is off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that works for me also with Android 6 Doze mode is on Service start command to call startForeground with a Notification and also acquire a partial Wake Lock. But your app will drain a little the battery